# bitcoind error "mempool min fee not met" preventing me from sending btc on blockchain

Tags: bitcoind, sending, error

When I want to send btc in block chain this message is appearing:

> BitcoindException(super=com.neemre.btcdcli4j.core.BitcoindException:
>   Error #-26: 66: mempool min fee not met, code=-26).

Who knows how to resolve this? Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR it probably means tx traffic is high and you need to set a higher feerate on your transaction.

"mempool min fee not met" isn't the minimum relay feerate setting (-minrelaytxfee); that error is "min relay fee not met".

When you get "mempool min fee not met" error, that refers to the node's dynamic mempool minimum feerate. It means the node's mempool reached capacity and started evicting the lowest feerate transactions, and temporarily raised the minimum feerate beyond the minimum relay feerate (to avoid accepting stuff that's going to be evicted immediately afterward).

Comment: related: [What if the mempool exceeds 300 MB?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96070/5406)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue on Electrum. Try a different server:   https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/3555#issuecomment-352621941

Answer (score 0):

Some servers set custom min Mempool fee, so the server that blockchain chose has set that option.

In blockchain.info you can't choose custom bitcoin server, So you should get your recovery phrase and import it in electrum since they support this feature. Or you can just wait until that server gets change.