# What is the difference between the txsize in mempool and mempool dynamic usage?

Tags: mempool, transaction-weight

There is a table for the txsize in mempool and dynamic memory usage of mempool on [statoshi.info's mempool overview](https://statoshi.info/d/000000020/memory-pool?orgId=1&from=now-24h&to=now)?
The default size of mempool defined in Bitcoin is 300MB, so is this default size the total txsize or the dynamic memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Mempool Transactions (the top graph) gives the total raw byte size of the serialized transaction data in mebibytes (1 MiB = 1024² bytes). Note that this is not equivalent to transaction weight (1 MvB = 1000² vbytes)—the transaction weight of the mempool is currently ~102.9 MvB, but this graph shows 96.1 MiB.

A node's mempool limit pertains to the dynamic memory usage of the deserialized transactions which for the 96.1 MiB of serialized data and 102.9 MvB of transaction weight is currently just shy of the 300 MiB limit with 286 MiB.

You may also find [What if the mempool exceeds 300 MB?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96068/5406) interesting.